# Python: trying to avoid using a global variable for a time_passed function

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, global-variables

I am new to Python and am using a method time_passed() for keeping track of how much time has passed.

I would prefer not to use a global variable.  Is there a way to write this method so that it doesn't take any parameters and it doesn't use a global variable?

```
import time

start_time=time.time()    
def time_passed():
    return time.time() - start_time
```

What is the pythonic way to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "timestamp"? if it's a real time-stamp, why would you need a "reference"/"start" time? Saying you do need, you'll have no choice rather than define your initial measuring time...

Comment: Good point.  It really should be called time_passed.  I'll update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: global variables are not evil. If you absolutely want to avoid a global here, you could use a generator function that encapsulates state

Comment: How would you encapsulate state?  That's what I am hoping to do.  A static, enscapsulated state would be perfect.  I am trying to avoid a global variable so as not to pollute the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static variable equivalent in Python is similar to Javascript where assigning a variable under a particular object namespace gives it persistence outside of method scope it was assigned in. Just like in Javascript, Python functions are objects and can be assigned member variables.

So for this example you could write

```
import time

def timestamp():
    timestamp.start_time=time.time()
    return time.time() - timestamp.start_time
```

Edit: now looking at the code however, you clearly want to initialize once and this function will reinitialize start_time per call. I am not so experienced in Python but this may work

```
import time

def timestamp():
    if timestamp.start_time is None:
        timestamp.start_time=time.time()
    return time.time() - timestamp.start_time
```

Comment: Cool.  I figured that there was a nice way to do this.  :-)

Comment: No worries Dan.  I just changed start_time to timestamp.start_time.  So, it worked fine.  :-)  The only catch is that the function needs to be defined before the assignment.

Comment: BTW, is None doesn't work when I test it on python 2.7.  What does work is using hasttr.  So, for another use case, I used: if not hasattr(timestamp,"start_time"): and that works.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple class storing the start time:

```
import time

class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = time.time()

    def __call__(self):
        return time.time() - self.start
```

Then use it like:

```
time_passed = Timer()
print time_passed()
```

This way you can easily use multiple timers as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I will keep this in mind.  I think that this is not needed for time_passed but it will work great for some other situations.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generator should be used for functions that need to encapsulate state.

```
import time


def time_passed_generator():
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        yield time.time() - start_time

time_passed = time_passed_generator()

#start

next(time_passed) # should be about 0.0

# ... later get the time passed

print(next(time_passed))
```